# Iterating over rows in a dataframe, performing calculations on each and putting answer in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Somewhat new to python. Effectively what I'm interested in doing is iterating over rows in a dataframe, performing a calculation on a specific column if a condition is met, and then having the answer be placed on the same row in a new column.

For sake of example, if I had a dataframe:

```
   c1  c2 
0  20  82
1  15  14
2  10  19
```

I may want to half the value in c1 if the value in c2 is greater than fifty, double the value in c1 if the value in c2 is less than fifty, and have the answers appear in a new column, c3, so I'd end up with:

```
   c1  c2  c3
0  20  82  10
1  15  14  30
2  10  19  20
```

I'm aware of how to do the maths bit, and how to use if/else functions, its just iterating over the rows I'm struggling with and how to put each answer into the new column. I'm aware of iterrows, but I'm not convinced I fully understand how to use it, or if its appropriate in this instance?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The direct way is to assign it to a new column inside the same dataframe. If the name exists, column gets replaced. Else it is appended.

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[20,15,10],'c2':[82,14,19]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   c1  c2
0  20  82
1  15  14
2  10  19

In [6]: df['c3'] = df['c1'] + df['c2']

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   c1  c2   c3
0  20  82  102
1  15  14   29
2  10  19   29

In [8]: df['c4'] = 10

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   c1  c2   c3  c4
0  20  82  102  10
1  15  14   29  10
2  10  19   29  10
```

The if-else thing can be achieved using anonymous functions:

```
In [13]: df['c5'] = df['c2'].apply(lambda x: x if x > 50 else 'nope')

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   c1  c2   c3  c4    c5
0  20  82  102  10    82
1  15  14   29  10  nope
2  10  19   29  10  nope
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [20, 15, 10], 'c2': [82, 14, 19]})

df['c3'] = np.where(df['c2'] > 50, df['c1'] * 0.5, df['c1'] * 2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   c1  c2    c3
0  20  82  10.0
1  15  14  30.0
2  10  19  20.0
```

---

Explanation of `np.where(df['c2'] > 50, df['c1'] * 0.5, df['c1'] * 2)`:

1. The first part (= `df['c2'] > 50`) is the condition we're checking (in this case comparing the `c2` column to 50, as you specified in the question).
2. The second part (= `df['c1'] * 0.5`) is the value we compute for cases where the condition was `True`.
3. The third part (= `df['c1'] * 2`) is the value we compute for cases where the condition was `False`.